# A way to group controls in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In Adobe Illustrator and other drawing programs I can group objects so I can move them together, resize them together, or treat them as a single object when I'm doing alignments. Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio 2012? I've seen GroupBox, but that's not what I want because that's a programming object instead of a behavior of the IDE. And how can I make it such that I can, say, keep two controls fixed in position but still align or change the spacing of third a third with respect to them?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Forms you group controls by dropping them inside the same container. Then moving the container, or disabling it, or hiding it, anything really, also affects every child object too.

Rather than a `GroupBox` though, I'd recommend a `Panel`. It's a light weight object who's sole purpose is to just host controls.

Comment: Does that involve simply clicking a menu item like "Group" in Adobe Illustrator?

Comment: A `Panel` is a windows form control which can contain other controls and such. Just drag it onto the form from the toolbox and drag/drob desired controls into it. If you want it to be strictly logical and in the IDE only, set the `GenerateMember` to `False` and set the `Margin` and `Padding` values to 0 in the properties window. That way it's only defined in the designer files and can only be accessed through the designer in Visual Studio and you won't see any weird spacing around other controls at run time.

Comment: @Melab, I tried to hint at it, but basically what you want isn't an IDE construct, and any IDE that does that only is taking the lazy way out. Those "grouped" controls have to behave cohesively at runtime too -- you need a way to group them together in a persistent way so that if you disable the item host you disable everything in it too. WinForms does it with explicit controls that host other controls.

Comment: The OP was more than likely looking for something that was only effective on the GUI of the IDE.  This way you could select "groups" of controls which will maintain all the same visual spacing/positions.  Previous versions of VS had this where they would "bind" the label to a textbox so they were "paired" up with one another.  The functionality would not be part of this "grouping" so run-time wouldn't have an affect or even be considered it's strictly from a design aspect.  Hence the reference to Adobe Illustrator, Flash, Fireworks, Photoshop all have this type of feature for object grouping.

Comment: Right, and what I tried to explain is that in the .NET world grouping is a hierarchical construct in code, and why. I mean you can downvote and complain all you want, it doesn't change this simple fact.